# I have in app purchase but after buy its not adding coins

Tags: android

Here is a code of purchase but after purchase text not changing to 9

**i just want to make changes to add 9 coins** but still not adding so i have posted full code can you see where is mistake why coins not adding after buy and 1 more thing why people cant buy item more than once i have enabled in google that people can buy more than once dear

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.TransactionDetails;

public class BuyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {
    private BillingProcessor bp;
    private TextView tvSubmit, tvNext;
    TextView tvCoin, tvBuy;
    private EditText etfname, etsecondname, etaddress;
    private TransactionDetails purchaseTransactionDetails = null;
    public static String MyPREFERENCES = "inapp";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy);
        init();
        clickListener();
    }

    private void clickListener() {
        tvNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = "google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void init() {
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedpreferences.getBoolean("purchase", false);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        etfname = findViewById(R.id.etfname);
        etsecondname = findViewById(R.id.et_secondname);
        etaddress = findViewById(R.id.et_address);
        tvSubmit = findViewById(R.id.tv_submit);
        tvCoin = findViewById(R.id.tvcoin);
        tvBuy = findViewById(R.id.tvbuy);
        tvNext = findViewById(R.id.tv_next);
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, getResources().getString(R.string.play_console_license), this);
        bp.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
        int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
        coins = coins + 9;
        tvCoin.setText(coins);
    // store value of coins variable instead of hardcoded number
        sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 9).apply();
        startActivity(new Intent(BuyActivity.this, ProcessingActivity.class));
        finish();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onProductPurchased: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onPurchaseHistoryRestored: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingError: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: ");

        String premium = getResources().getString(R.string.premium);

        purchaseTransactionDetails = bp.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails(premium);

        bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
        tvBuy.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            if (bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported()) {
                bp.subscribe(this, premium);
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: Subscription updated is not supported");
            }
        });
        tvSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String fname, sname, address;
            fname = etfname.getText().toString();
            sname = etsecondname.getText().toString();
            address = etaddress.getText().toString();
           /* if (!fname.isEmpty()) {
                if (!sname.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!address.isEmpty()) {*/
            int coin = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
            if (coin < 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyActivity.this);
                ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, viewGroup, false);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk).setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    if (bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported()) {
                        bp.subscribe(this, premium);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: Subscription updated is not supported");
                    }
                });
                if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean("inapp", false)) {

                } else {

                }
            }

                   /* } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Address is Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Second Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter First Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/

        });

       /* if (hasSubscription()) {
            tvStatus.setText("Status: Premium");
        } else {
            tvStatus.setText("Status: Free");
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean hasSubscription() {
        if (purchaseTransactionDetails != null) {
            return purchaseTransactionDetails.purchaseInfo != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its probably because you are setting the value of `coins` to zero on purchase. `sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 0).apply();` You should use the value of `coins` here.

Comment: dear check my code and tell me thankx

Comment: now you can tell me the code dear

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) about `SharedPreferences`. 
 Let me briefly explain what your code lines are doing:

```
int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
```

↑ This line looks up whether a key named "coins" exists in the SharedPreferences. If the key **does not exist**, it takes **0 as default value**. Otherwise, it returns the **value that is associated** to the key.

```
sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 0).apply();
```

↑ This puts a key named "coins" into the SharedPreferences and **associates it** with the value 0.

So you are storing the value 0 in the SharedPreferences. If you then are reading the value of coins out of the SharedPreferences in another Activity, it will show 0.

You probably rather want to store the updated number of coins in the SharedPreferences. In order to achieve that, do this:

```
@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
    coins = coins + 9;
    tvCoin.setText(coins);
    // store value of coins variable instead of hardcoded number
    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", coins).apply();  
    startActivity(new Intent(BuyActivity.this, ProcessingActivity.class));
    finish();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onProductPurchased: ");
}
```

Comment: like this dear 


@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
    coins = coins + 9;
    tvCoin.setText(coins);
    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 9).apply();
    startActivity(new Intent(BuyActivity.this, ProcessingActivity.class));
    finish();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onProductPurchased: ");

Comment: @shvybanlin Not quite. With the code in your comment, you will always store the value 9 in the SharedPreferences. So if the user buys coins twice, he still has 9 coins instead of 18. Just store the value of the `coins` variable. I edited my answer to include the full code.

Comment: dear can you tell me about this one after buy when user g onext screen 5 coins got deducted is it wright code

Comment: app getting closed after adding this dear

Comment: This has to be caused by something else, as I actually suggested to only change one single line. You can investigate the cause by looking into the logs, the stacktrace of the crash will appear there. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Comment: @Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
    coins = coins + 9;
    tvCoin.setText(coins);
    sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 9 ).apply();
    startActivity(new Intent(BuyActivity.this, ProcessingActivity.class));
    finish();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onProductPurchased: ");
}

it is not working dear

Comment: i changed to 9 coins but still not adding dear

Comment: What is not adding? When you do `sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 9 ).apply();` it will ALWAYS only store the value 9, no matter how often you buy. As I already explained several times, use this exact line:
`sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", coins).apply(); `This will store the updated value in the SharedPreferences. Whenever you read out of these SharedPreferences, you will get the updated value that was stored there.

Comment: dear i want to put 9 coins every time who buy but its not working after buy 0 coin added dear

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else. The code in my answer 1) reads the current number of coins out of the sharedPreferences and stores it in a variable 2) increases the variable by 9 coins 3) stores the new value of the variable in the sharedPreferences. Each time you call this code, the coins in the sharedPreferences will be increased by 9. So this is exactly what you want. The problem must lie somewhere else, maybe `onProductPurchased` is not even called.

Comment: should i post here full code dear

Comment: You can edit your question and include more code, yes, that would be helpful.

Comment: now code has updated can you tell me dear